# Popunder that works on all browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

I am currently using

```
window.open(url).blur()
window.focus()
```

but this only works properly in chrome. In IE the window comes back up when it's done loading. In firefox, the window does not go under at all. Don't worry, this popunder is not going to be annoying as the user will expect it/want it.

Comment: I find myself deeply intrigued by this concept of user-wanted popunder, and wish to subscribe to your newsletter.

Comment: I always wonder how imagevenue.com(inspect page source?) does that, but I also find it incredible annoying!

Comment: How about a keep alive window? Something that pings the server and keeps the session from dying. That could be wanted? Just trying to think of a good reason to popunder.

Comment: Trust me. It's a secret though

Comment: This script is supposed to do what you're trying to do:
https://gist.github.com/1021924

Comment: This solution should work too, not tested though: http://goo.gl/f79vq